# Issue with variables/functions in solving equations

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, variable-definitions

I've been posting some questions all around issues with defining and using variables/functions in Mathematica. 
Based on the answers/comments I got I still cannot make this simple code work... Why is this not working?

```
d1 = 50;
u22 = 1;
s22 = u22*0.25;
d2 = 1;
p2=1;
F = 0.95;

FS22[x_] := 
  CDF[GumbelDistribution[u22 - EulerGamma*s22*6^0.5/Pi, s22*6^0.5/Pi],
    x];

FS2[x_?NumericQ] := ((1 - p2)*UnitStep[x] + p2*FS22[x])^(d1/d2);

NSolve[F == FS2[x], x, Reals]
```

Result:

```
Out[1056]= NSolve[0.95 == FS2[x], x, Reals]
```

Another try:

```
NSolve[
 F == ((1 - p2)*UnitStep[x] + 
     p2*CDF[GumbelDistribution[u22 - EulerGamma*s22*6^0.5/Pi, 
        s22*6^0.5/Pi], x])^(d1/d2), x, Reals]
```

Result:

```
Out[1057]= {{x -> 1.2635}}
```

Comment: I get the same answer both times and a plot of `FS2[x]-F` agrees with the result.

Comment: @BillWatts Thank you for the feedback. I just restarted Mathematica and I don't get the same answer. I get what I show above. The version I'm working is 12.0.0.0.

Comment: I use the same version.  With the first result I get warning messages, but it spits out the answer, but slower than the second result.  But both are the same.

Comment: @BillWatts I copy paste the code above in a new notebook and the result I get is `NSolve[0.95 == FS2[x], x, Reals]` Do you have any option activated or something that it can justify these different results? I just installed Mathematica yesterday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for general syntax tips, I highly suggest reading around here for syntax posts, there are lots of them. However [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28073/48686) and others might be helpful.

With your code I suggest never using upper case letters as mathematica commands and code always starts with Capitals...though F is not one of them, get in the habit to start your variables with lowercase letters.

```
d1 = 50;
u22 = 1;
s22 = u22 0.25;
d2 = 1;
p2 = 1;
f = 0.95;

FS22[x_] := CDF[GumbelDistribution[u22 - EulerGamma s22 6^0.5/\[Pi], s22 6^0.5/\[Pi]], x]

FS2[x_] := ((1 - p2) UnitStep[x] + p2 FS22[x])^(d1/d2)

NSolve[f == FS2[x], x, Reals]

{{x -> 1.2635}}
```

This is what I had to do to modify your code to get it to work.

Namely I removed `?NumericQ`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the link! Your suggestion really works. However, I'm struggling still with another example! See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215667/881. Any help is appreciated!