# Issue with Solve, NSolve, FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, variable-definitions

I have this code that I've been trying to get working for some time. I asked some questions before which helped but still struggling!

```
u11 = 1;
s11 = u11*0.05;
d1 = 50; p1 = 1.0;
u22 = 1;
s22 = u22*0.25;
d2 = 1; p2 = 1;
t0 = 50;
F = 0.95;

fS11[r_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[u11, s11], r]
fS1[x_] := (1 - p1)*DiracDelta[x] + p1*fS11[x]

FS22[x_] :=CDF[GumbelDistribution[u22 - EulerGamma*s22*6^0.5/Pi,s22*6^0.5/Pi], x];
FS2[x_?NumericQ] := ((1 - p2)*UnitStep[x] + p2*FS22[x])^(d1/d2)

FS12[x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[fS1[y]*FS2[x - y], {y, -Infinity, +Infinity}];

Solve[F == FS12[x], x, Reals]
```

I get the frustrating result:

```
Out[391]= {{x -> ["FS12"]^-1[0.95]}}
```

Although FindRoot eventually finds the correct result...

```
FindRoot[F == FS12[x], {x, 2.2}]

Out[392]= {x -> 2.29452}
```

And `Solve[F == F12[x], x, Reals]` works like a charm

```
{{x -> 1.2635}}
```

And I have no error when I ask to Plot `FS12`

```
Plot[FS12[x], {x, 1, 3}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

How to get the NSolve working?

Comment: @Bill Thank you for the reply! However I very much prefer Solve or NSolve over FindRoot since I don't want to have an educated starting value because that would mean I would have to solve the problem myself. Why NSolve or Solve don't work?

Comment: This is intrinsically a root-finding problem. `NSolve` has no methods for handling a "black box" type of function.

Comment: To expand on @DanielLichtblau's comment, since `FS12` is defined numerically, you can't expect `Solve` to find an analytical result, so you're stuck with `FindRoot`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, @ChrisK so why does `Solve[F == FS2[x], x, Reals]` work?

Comment: @jpcgandre It doesn't work with the `_?NumericQ`.  You might have an old definition without it that let's it give you a result.  Anyhow, `FS12` has `NIntegrate` in it.  How could you expect an analytical result with `NIntegrate` on the right hand side?

Comment: @ChrisK You are correct all the way! Thank you!!!